# RVM error when running cd command

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have set up rvm to manage all my ruby version.

All things is working, and I installed ruby1.2.6. But I'm getting error when cd to any directory hosting a ruby application. for example :

```
admin@hostname-10:~ $ cd /var/www 
ruby-1.9.3-p448 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448'
admin@hostname-10:/var/www $ ruby -v 
ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x86_64-linux]
admin@hostname-10:/var/www $ 

admin@hostname-10:/var/www $ sudo -s
ruby-1.9.3-p448 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448'
hostname-10# 

hostname-10# pwd
/var/www
hostname-10#
```

What and where can be the issue? What cd invokes here?

Thanks.

Comment: It tries to set the appropriate Ruby. How about installing the Ruby the project wants?

Comment: Do you want to try to run this project with `2.1.6` or to use the ruby this project explicitly requires? If first, try to `cd /var/www && mv .rvm .rvm.orig`. If second, `rvm install 1.9.3-p448`.

Comment: Yes @DaveNewton normally it tries to create and generate gemset, but is using **ruby1.9.3**, why should use **ruby.2.1.6** from   **/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6**.
Why is it  still using **ruby1.9.3**? And I don't understand the question **"How about installing the Ruby the project wants?"**

Comment: @mudasobwa, I want to use 2.1.6, but I have non **.rvm** in my */var/www* directory

Comment: The requirement might be in `Gemfile` as well. Try to `grep -r '1.9.3' /var/www`.

Comment: It seems like my rvm env is not well set either for admin or root root user. I can't copy the result of the command **env | grep -i rvm** here. But it's defferent than the one from a working system.
Can this be the matter? Where to configure the right system wide rvm environnement variables setting please?

Comment: I tried all this @mudasobwa, but now I can see that the other environment variables comes from the application. When i run the *d** command, it loads other environment variables. And I can see that there particularly missing the **rvm_ruby_string** variable and the **rvm_recommended_ruby** variable is set to  **rvm_recommended_ruby=rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448**
I'm looking for how to locate and fixe that. I would like know what files the **cd** command is loading

Comment: And @mudasobwa, in the Gemfile, I have this at top of the file : **ruby '2.1.6'**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quiet simple.

The application was writen in ruby1.9.3 and required it.

The application will be be update as the ruby version has been updated.

I did the same tests with an up to date code and it works.

Regards.